# How can I elegantly find the next and previous value in a Python Enum?

Tags: python, python-3.x, enums, iterator

I have a simple enum in Python that looks like this:

```
from enum import Enum

class MyEnum(Enum):
    #All members have increasing non-consecutive integer values.
    A = 0
    B = 2
    C = 10
    D = 18
    ...
```

I want functions `pred()` and `succ()` that given a member of `MyEnum` return the member of `MyEnum` that precedes and succeeds the given element, respectively (just like [the functions of the same name in Haskell](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Enum)). For example `succ(MyEnum.B)` and `pred(MyEnum.D)` should both return `MyEnum.C`. An exception can be raised if `succ` is called on the last member of `pred` is called on the first member.

There doesn't seem to be any built in method to do this, and while I can call `iter(MyEnum)` to iterate over the values it has to go through the whole enum from the beginning. I could probably implement a sloppy loop to accomplish this on my own, but I know there are some real Python gurus on this site, so to you I ask: is there a better approach?

Comment: The purpose of `enum` in Python is to provide a data type that can be used in place of "magic numbers" and such, not really to provide a mathematical data type corresponding to enumerable sets. So the purpose of Haskell's `enum` is slightly different. In any case nothing prevents you from implementing `pred` and `succ` as methods of `MyEnum`.

Comment: Provided simple translation of the answer in that question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Note that you can provide `succ` and `pred` methods inside an `Enum` class:

```
class Sequential(Enum):
    A = 1
    B = 2
    C = 4
    D = 8
    E = 16

    def succ(self):
        v = self.value * 2
        if v > 16:
            raise ValueError('Enumeration ended')
        return Sequential(v)

    def pred(self):
        v = self.value // 2
        if v == 0:
            raise ValueError('Enumeration ended')
        return Sequential(v)
```

Used as:

```
>>> import myenums
>>> myenums.Sequential.B.succ()
<Sequential.C: 4>
>>> myenums.Sequential.B.succ().succ()
<Sequential.D: 8>
>>> myenums.Sequential.B.succ().succ().pred()
<Sequential.C: 4>
```

Obviously this is efficient only if you actually have a simple way to compute the values from an item to the next or preceding one, which may not always be the case.

If you want a general efficient solution at the cost of adding some space, you can build the mappings of the successor and predecessor functions.
You have to add these as attributes *after* the creation of the class (since `Enum` messes up attributes) so you can use a decorator to do that:

```
def add_succ_and_pred_maps(cls):
    succ_map = {}
    pred_map = {}
    cur = None
    nxt = None
    for val in cls.__members__.values():
        if cur is None:
            cur = val
        elif nxt is None:
            nxt = val

        if cur is not None and nxt is not None:
            succ_map[cur] = nxt
            pred_map[nxt] = cur
            cur = nxt
            nxt = None
    cls._succ_map = succ_map
    cls._pred_map = pred_map

    def succ(self):
        return self._succ_map[self]

    def pred(self):
        return self._pred_map[self]

    cls.succ = succ
    cls.pred = pred
    return cls





@add_succ_and_pred_maps
class MyEnum(Enum):
    A = 0
    B = 2
    C = 8
    D = 18
```

Used as:

```
>>> myenums.MyEnum.A.succ()
<MyEnum.B: 2>
>>> myenums.MyEnum.B.succ()
<MyEnum.C: 8>
>>> myenums.MyEnum.B.succ().pred()
<MyEnum.B: 2>
>>> myenums.MyEnum._succ_map
{<MyEnum.A: 0>: <MyEnum.B: 2>, <MyEnum.C: 8>: <MyEnum.D: 18>, <MyEnum.B: 2>: <MyEnum.C: 8>}
```

you probably want a custom exception instead of `KeyError` but you get the idea.

---

There probably is a way to integrate the last step using metaclasses, but it's notstraightforward for the simple fact that`Enum`s are implemented using metaclasses and it's not trivial to compose metaclasses.

Comment: Your answer was very helpful in two ways: it solved my problem, and, the solution was sufficiently complicated that I'm now fairly convinced that an enum is a poor choice of data structure for what I'm trying to do in Python. Thanks for your assistance!

Answer (score 4):

Adding your `next` and `prev` methods (or `succ` and `pred`) is easy enough:

```
def next(self):
    cls = self.__class__
    members = list(cls)
    index = members.index(self) + 1
    if index >= len(members):
        # to cycle around
        # index = 0
        #
        # to error out
        raise StopIteration('end of enumeration reached')
    return members[index]

def prev(self):
    cls = self.__class__
    members = list(cls)
    index = members.index(self) - 1
    if index < 0:
        # to cycle around
        # index = len(members) - 1
        #
        # to error out
        raise StopIteration('beginning of enumeration reached')
    return members[index]
```

Comment: Note that the `index` method raises a `ValueError` when the element wasn't found, you want to use the `find` method instead to get `-1` when not found. Also this solution requires going through all members at least once and possibly twice, so isn't really much efficient.

Comment: @Bakuriu:  `.index()` is okay to use in this case because the member will always be found.  On average it only goes through half the members, and never twice.

Comment: No, `list(cls)` goes through **all** elements once, and then `members.index` on average goes through half the members, but it's still more than one time for every member for every call. It's more efficient to do a simple `for i, member in enumerate(cls)` loop and keep track of the previous element of each iteration.

Comment: @Bakuriu: Ah, right you are.  And the `list()` portion is Python code, too.  The `Index()`, though, is C code, so I suspect the final speed is either still faster with my approach, or very close.

Comment: @Bakuriu:  I think the important point is that my code is simpler and much easier to understand.  On the other hand if, after measuring, my code proved to be a bottleneck and was hurting overall performance, then I would go with something similar to your caching-style code.